# Unable to install DLIB on python 3.7.6

Tags: python, visual-studio, mingw, python-3.7, dlib

I am creating a face recognition system using python 3.7.6.
For that, the dependencies are:

1. opencv-python
2. cmake
3. dlib

I have successfully installed `opencv-python`, `cmake`

But while installing the dlib library for `Python 3.7.6`. I received an error:

```
Collecting
https: // files.pythonhosted.org / packages / 1
e / 62 / aacb236d21fbd08148b1d517d58a9d80ea31bdcd386d26f21f8b23b1eb28 / dlib - 19.18
.0.tar.gz
Using
cached
dlib - 19.18
.0.tar.gz(3.1
MB)
Using
legacy
'setup.py install'
for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing
collected
packages: dlib
Running
setup.py
install
for dlib...error
    ERROR: Command
    errored
    out
    with exit status 1:
        command: 'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face-Attendance\venv\Scripts\python.exe' - u - c
    'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\\setup.py
'"'"'; __file__='"'"'
C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\\setup.py
'"'"';f = getattr(t
okenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO(
    '"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');
code = f.read().replace('"'"'\
r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))
' install --record '
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip - record - gf1sikyf\install - record.
    txt
' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '
C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face - Attendance\venv\include\site\python3
.7\dlib
'
cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb \
    Complete
output(57
lines):
running
install
running
build
running
build_py
package
init
file
'dlib\__init__.py'
not found( or not a
regular
file)
running
build_ext
Building
extension
for Python 3.7.6 (tags / v3.7.6:43364
a7ae0, Dec
19
2019, 00: 42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit(AMD64)]
Invoking
CMake
setup: 'cmake C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-s30f1uyb\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\p
ip - req - build - s30f1uyb\build\lib.win - amd64 - 3.7 - DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE = C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face - Attendance\venv\Scripts\python.exe - DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTOR
Y_RELEASE = C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\build\lib.win - amd64 - 3.7 - A
x64
'
- - Building
for: NMake
Makefiles
CMake
Error
at
CMakeLists.txt: 3(project):
Generator

NMake
Makefiles

does
not support
platform
specification, but
platform

x64

was
specified.

    CMake
Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER
not set, after
EnableLanguage
CMake
Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
not set, after
EnableLanguage
- - Configuring
incomplete, errors
occurred!
See
also
"C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-s30f1uyb/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback(most
recent
call
last):
File
"<string>", line
1, in < module >
        File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-s30f1uyb\setup.py", line
261, in < module >
          'Topic :: Software Development',
          File
"C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face-Attendance\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line
153, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line
148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line
966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line
985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File
"C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face-Attendance\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line
61, in run
return orig.install.run(self)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line
545, in run
self.run_command('build')
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line
313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line
985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line
135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line
313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line
985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-s30f1uyb\setup.py", line
135, in run
self.build_extension(ext)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-s30f1uyb\setup.py", line
172, in build_extension
subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
File
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line
363, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
'['
cmake
', '
C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\\tools\\python
', ' - DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
=C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\\build\\lib.win - amd64 - 3.7
', ' - DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE = C:\\Users\\hp\\PycharmProjects\\Face - Attendance\\venv\ \
    Scripts\\python.exe
', ' - DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE = C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip - req - build - s30f1uyb\\build\\lib.win - amd64 - 3.7
', ' - A
', '
x64
']'
returned
non - zero
exit
status
1.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command
errored
out
with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face-Attendance\venv\Scripts\python.exe' - u - c
'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize;
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-s30f1uyb\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__ = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-s30f
1u
yb\\setup.py
'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'
open
'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'
from setuptools import setup;

setup()
'"'"
');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
install - -record
'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pi
p - record - gf1sikyf\install - record.txt
' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '
C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Face - Attendance\venv\include\site \
    python3
.7\dlib
' Check the logs for full command output.
```

But I already have an C++ Compiler known as MinGW and also can access it through `gcc` in the terminal.

But How to make DLIB use my MinGW compiler instead of Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you using anaconda? You can try to open a new env and doing a clean install.

Comment: Sorry, but i am using pure python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dlib 19.22 build just fine with MinGW-w64 under [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell.

I use [cmake](https://cmake.org/) to configure and [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) to build.

No special `cmake` parameters are needed apart from `-G"MSYS Makefiles"` to use MSYS' `make`. Or you could use `-GNinja` instead to specify `ninja` as build tool, which is a lot faster.

For release builds you can also add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release`.

Finally you can set `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` for static build or `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON` for shared build.

So in short, to build shared dlib with MSYS' make you can do this (change `/path/where/to/install` to the desired install location):

```
cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/path/where/to/install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -S. -Bbuild_shared
make -Cbuild_shared install/strip
```

Answer (score 0):

Dlib requires core c++ dependencies to compile. I recommended you to use deepface. It is more lightweight.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg")
```